# jQuery count value of select option inside nested div

Tags: jquery, html

In jQuery i would like to write a simple function to show an alert if the difference of sum of values selected inside select box is > 0, for each div of same class.

This is my html code:

```js
    $(".Y").each(function( index ) {
     var positive = $(this).children('.Z').val();
     var negative = 0;
    
     $(this).children('.T').each(function( index ) {
      negative = negative + $(this).val();
     });
     
     var difference = positive - negative;
    
     if (difference > 0 ) {
      alert("Show something!");
     }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="X">
     <div class="Y">
      <select class="Z">
       <option value="0">0</option>
       <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
      <select class="T">
       <option value="0">0</option>
       <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
      <select class="T">
       <option value="0">0</option>
       <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
      <div>

     <div class="Y">
      <select class="Z">
       <option value="0">0</option>
       <option value="1">1</option>
       </select>
      <select class="T">
       <option value="0">0</option>
       <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
      <select class="T">
       <option value="0">0</option>
       <option value="1">1</option>
     </select>
        <div>
    <div>
```

My code is not working. Where i'm wrong? Some hint?

Comment: Do you have an errore message for us?

Comment: try .find('option:selected').attr('value') instead of .val()

Comment: @twicejr: There's no reason to do that at all. It's not like `val` is broken.

Comment: It usually doesn't work when the user changes the selectbox. It's just outputting the selected="selected" one.

Comment: @twicejr: Again: `val` is not broken. Proof: https://jsfiddle.net/o9b7779u/

Comment: I'm getting old. https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7889

Comment: @twicejr: Wow, that's...an old bug. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var difference = positive - negative;

if (differenze > 0 ) {
    alert("Show something!");
}
```

You spelled it **differenze** instead of **difference**.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".Z, .T").on("change", function( index ) {
      var positive = $(this).parent().children('.Z').val();
      var negative = 0;

      $(this).parent().children('.T').each(function( index ) {
          negative = negative + $(this).val();
      });

      var difference = positive - negative;

      if (difference > 0 ) {
          alert("Show something!");
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="X">
    <div class="Y">
        <select class="Z">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
        </select>
        <select class="T">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
        </select>
        <select class="T">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
        </select>
    <div>

    <div class="Y">
        <select class="Z">
            <option >0</option>
            <option >1</option>
        </select>
        <select class="T">
            <option >0</option>
            <option >1</option>
        </select>
        <select class="T">
            <option >0</option>
            <option >1</option>
       </select>
    <div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help! The main problem, it's that i'm a stupid...

```
    negative = negative + $(this).val();
```

means append negative variable with $(this).val(). Not means do an algebraic sum.

Very ugly solution:

```
    negative = negative - -$(this).val();
```

Or much better:

```
    negative = negative + parseInt($(this).val());
```

Now it works!